# Define operators required to be a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can you define operators $\oplus$ and $\circ$ such that $\{0, 1, 2\}$ is a vector space over the field $Z_2$.

Here's what I did:-

For the vector space $V$ ,I defined $\oplus$ as $(x+y) \mod 3$ where $x,y \in V$
and $\circ$ as $(x\circ y) \mod 3$. Then all the axioms required to be a vector space is satisfied. Am I correct?

Comment: I have just started studying vector spaces and is on the second unit of Friedberg book on Linear algebra. Still now I haven't studied dimensions. It is a class assignment .

Comment: @SayantanBanerjee You need to define multiplication for a scalar multiply with vector, but not multiplication between vectors. Otherwise it looks fine to me. Since it is just normal multiplication and addition, the axioms for distributive laws/ commutativity, associativity, etc must all be satisfied. You just need to verify that it is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Your attempts get into trouble with the following part of the definition of vector space: For any $a, b \in \Bbb Z_2$ and any $v \in V$ we have $(a+b)v = av+bv$. Try it out with $a = b = 1$, and see what the problem is.

Comment: @Arthur so if I define + is (x+y) mod 3 and . as usual multiplication then (1+1).2=1.2+1.2 = 2+2=1. Is it right?

Comment: @SayantanBanerjee The cardinality of a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-vector space is a power of $2$. It follows that you should be trying to prove why the set *cannot* be given the structure of a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @SayantanBanerjee Yes, that's one half of it. The other half is that in $\Bbb Z_2$, we have $1+1=0$, so $(1+1)\cdot2=1$ as per your calculations, and at the same time $(1+1)\cdot2=0\cdot2=0$. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @Arthur Lets define x∘y=(x.y)mod 2 and x⊕y=(x+y) mod 2 , then the above problem doesn't exist. Am I right?

Comment: @SayantanBanertje But then, is the vector space really $\{0,1,2\}$, or is it $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @Arthur The vector space is {0,1,2} over the field {0,1}. For 1 ∈ F and 2∈V, we have (1+1).2=1.2+1.2=0+0=0 and LHS is also 0. Can you give some hint as to how should I proceed?

Comment: @SayantanBanerjee My point is, if you define the vector space addition as modulo $2$ addition as in your comment above, you don't really have the vector space $\{0,1,2\}$, but instead the vetor space $\{0,1\}$. Because $1\oplus 1 = 2$ but $1\oplus 1 = 0$ as well, so $2$ and $0$ are the same element.

Comment: Yeah I got your point. Can you help me with the answer or at least some hints?